# How can I do nested ordering?

Tags: templating, search, ordering

I want to put the index of section in order by two fields: `featured` and `startDate`. Basically, I want the `featured` entries to rise to the top of the index, and then within the featured posts I want them to be sorted by `startDate` field. Below the featured entries, I want the other entries to also be sorted by `startDate`.

I tried `entries.order('featured desc').order('startDate desc')` but, as I expected, it simply ordered by `startDate` because that method executed after ordering by `featured`.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm tring to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you the desired results:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('yoursection').order('startDate desc, featured desc') %}

    {# Entry Code #}

{% endfor %}
```

If for any reason that doesn't achieve exactly what it is you are looking for, you could always break it up into multiple loops, 1 for featured, and 1 for not featured. It's not as clean as the above solution but should also solve the issue:

This will use 2 loops, one for the featured and 1 for the not featured, assuming the 'featured' field is a lightswitch.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('yoursection').search('featured:1').order('startDate desc') %}

    {# Entry Code #}

{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('yoursection').search('featured:not 1').order('startDate desc') %}

    {# Entry Code #}

{% endfor %}
```